# Develop a software like FireBug?

Tags: html, css, firebug

I have a project and this project includes a module about web page html and css properties. I have to get all the html tags and their relative css properties and values in a hierarchical way like FireBug.

What i mean may be more understandable if i show a pic:

[screenshot http://img33.imageshack.us/img33/3279/firebug.jpg](http://img33.imageshack.us/img33/3279/firebug.jpg)

How can i retrieve css properties of html selectors of a web page like the image above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may help to familiarize yourself with how Firebug does it:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Firebug_internals
- http://fbug.googlecode.com/svn/

Comment: These codes are written in JavaScript.. Can't i develop a software to retrieve html and css codes in C# or other programming language?

Comment: Sure you can, and we wish you the best of luck!  Javascript is just far and away the best tool for HTML and CSS. (Try 'Javascript: the Good Parts' by D. Crockford)

Comment: You would primarily need any language that has 2 libraries - 1 for DOM parsing and 1 for CSS parsing.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about simply embedding a module like firebug, why not try their javascript version?  You don't need the firefox plugin, and can use it in any browser: http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite

Answer (score 0):

This can help you [firebug wiki](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page)